# Core Data Custom Class Unknown Linker Error

Tags: core-data, ios4, linker

Ey guys, I have been referencing [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TaggedLocations/Introduction/Intro.html) project, but I get this linker error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParkingLot in ParkingLot.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Permit in Permit.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ParkingLot in ParkingLot.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Permit in Permit.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the relevant code(that I made following [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/03_ManagedObject.html)[scroll down to "Custom Managed Object Class"]):

```
//Permit.h
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class ParkingLot;

@interface Permit :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * eligibility;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * pricing;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * summary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * timeValid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* parkingLots;

@end


@interface Permit (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addParkingLotsObject:(ParkingLot *)value;
- (void)removeParkingLotsObject:(ParkingLot *)value;
- (void)addParkingLots:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeParkingLots:(NSSet *)value;

@end

//Permit.m
#import "Permit.h"

#import "ParkingLot.h"

@implementation Permit 

@dynamic eligibility;
@dynamic pricing;
@dynamic type;
@dynamic summary;
@dynamic timeValid;
@dynamic parkingLots;

@end

//ParkingLot.h
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface ParkingLot :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id region;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* permits;

@end


@interface ParkingLot (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addPermitsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removePermitsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addPermits:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removePermits:(NSSet *)value;

@end

//ParkingLot.m
#import "ParkingLot.h"


@implementation ParkingLot 

@dynamic title;
@dynamic region;
@dynamic permits;

@end
```

If you take a look at the sample code I followed, it is pretty much identical, yet it refuses to work and I can't figure out why. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stupid me... I needed to add the Core Data framework to my project. I could have sworn I had already done this... that's what I get for programming into the wee hours of the morning.

Comment: I made the same mistake. +1 for the simple, obvious solution.